# List indicies must be integers or slices, not datetime.datetime

Tags: python, list

sorry for a noob question, I'm new to python so here's my problem:

When trying to run the following code, with dates[0] defined by the user in previous code, for example-

`dates.append(2020 8 25)`

```
   for d in dates:
   checkexp = dates[d]
   if checkexp + timedelta(days = 7) < current:
        print('Food will expire within a week')
```

I get the error:
`list indices must be integers or slices, not datetime.datetime`

I'm probably just making a beginner mistake, but help would be appreciated!

If it's worth mentioning, the code run just before this works:

```
firstdate = dates[0]
print(firstdate.strftime('%d/%m/%y'))
```

Comment: When you iterate over a list in Python, you don't get indices, but the elements directly. So you can just do `for checkexp in dates:` and skip the following assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a for-each loop construct. When you perform a `for x in iterable` on an iterable, `x` here is not the index, but the element itself. So when you run `for d in dates`, Python is returning the `datetime` object in dates, not the index.

Instead, you must be doing:

```
for checkexp in dates:
   if checkexp + timedelta(days = 7) < current:
        print('Food will expire within a week')
```

Alternatively, if you want both the index and the element, you can use the `enumerate` function.

```
for i, checkexp in enumerate(dates):
    # You can access the element using either checkexp or dates[i].
    if checkexp + timedelta(days = 7) < current:
        print('Food will expire within a week')
```

If you must use the index, you can use the `len` function to get the length of the iterable, and access the list elements as you would in C. But this is un-Pythonic.

```
for i in range(len(dates)):
   if dates[i] + timedelta(days = 7) < current:
        print('Food will expire within a week')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for checkexp in dates:
   #checkexp = dates[d]
   if checkexp + timedelta(days = 7) < current:
        print('Food will expire within a week')
```